# Kiel traduki "rib cage" / "cage thoracique"?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

Mi serĉis en vortaro.net kaj en la *Medicina Esperanta Terminaro* (ĉefa kompilinto: D-ro Josef Hradil) sed mi ne trovis. Ĉu mi povas uzi la vorton *riparo*? Aŭ eble mi devas uzi ion kun la kapvorto *torako*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ka%C4%9Do) uses ***brustokaĝo*** or *brustokorbo* ("basket").

Technical dictionaries seem to be happy to give ***torako*** for the bones of the *abdomeno*. You could clarify that as ***toraka ostaro***.

*Riparo* would possibly be understood in context, but note carefully that it also means "a repair".

---

[PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ka%C4%9Do) provizas la vortojn ***brustokaĝo*** kaj *brustokorbo*.

Teknikaj vortaroj ŝajne sin kontentigas per ***torako*** por la ostoj de l' abdomeno, kaj oni povus klarigi tion per ***toraka ostaro***.

*Riparo* verŝajne kompreneblus laŭ kunteksto, sed rimarku ke tio ankaŭ estas substantiva formo de *ripari*.

Comment: Antaŭ ol klaki je ĉi demando por legi la respondojn, mi pensis: "riparo".

Do, tiu certe estus komprenebla laŭ kunteksto. Sed por maksimuma komprenebleco, mi samopinias pri la respondo de Andrew Woods. Dum rapida konversacio sen vortaroj, "riparo" verŝajne estas la vorto kiu elirus ies buŝo.